# Running non-root Docker within Ubuntu Docker container

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu

I'm trying to run a Docker build within a Docker container based upon Ubuntu 20.04. The container needs to run as a non-root use for the build process before the Docker build occurs.

Here's some snippets of my Dockerfile to show what I'm doing:

```
FROM amd64/ubuntu:20.04

# Install required packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y software-properties-common
                                        build-essential \
                                        libssl-dev \
                                        openssl \
                                        libsqlite3-dev \
                                        libtool \
                                        wget \
                                        autoconf \
                                        automake \
                                        git \
                                        make \
                                        pkg-config \
                                        cmake \
                                        doxygen \
                                        graphviz \
                                        docker.io

# Add user for CI purposes
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash ciuser
RUN passwd -d ciuser

# Set docker group membership
RUN usermod -aG docker ciuser

# Run bash as the non-root user
CMD ["su", "-", "ciuser", "/bin/bash"]
```

When I run the container up, and try to run docker commands, I get an error:

```
$ docker run -ti --privileged=true -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ci_container_staging
ciuser@0bb768506106:~$ docker ps
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/containers/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

If I remove the running as `ciuser` it works ok:

```
$ docker run -ti --privileged=true -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock /ci_container_staging
root@d71654581cec:/# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                  COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
d71654581cec        ci_container_staging   "/bin/bash"         3 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds                            vigilant_lalande
root@d71654581cec:/#
```

Where am I going wrong with setting up Docker via Dockerfile and then setting user to run as?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`amd64/ubuntu:20.04` has a `docker` group with group id 103.  Most likely the gid of the docker group for your local machine is not 103 (check `getent group docker`).  So even though `ciuser` is part of the `docker` group, the id is different and so the user is not granted access to the docker socket.

A simple fix would be to change the gid of the `docker` group in the container to match your host's:

```
RUN groupmod -g <HOST_DOCKER_GROUP_ID> docker
```

There are plenty of other ways to solve issues with mapping uid/gid to docker containers but this should give you enough information to move forward.

Example/more info:

```
# gid on docker socket is 998
root@c349e1d13b76:/# ls -al /var/run/docker.sock 
srw-rw---- 1 root 998 0 Apr 12 14:54 /var/run/docker.sock

# But gid of docker group is 103
root@c349e1d13b76:/# getent group docker
docker:x:103:ciuser

# root can `docker ps`
root@c349e1d13b76:/# docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE            COMMAND       CREATED              STATUS              PORTS     NAMES
c349e1d13b76   nonroot:latest   "/bin/bash"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute             kind_satoshi

# but fails for ciuser
root@c349e1d13b76:/# runuser -l ciuser -c 'docker ps'
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/containers/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied

# change docker gid in the container to match the one on the socket/localhost
# 998 is the docker gid on my machine, yours may (will) be different.
root@c349e1d13b76:/# groupmod -g 998 docker

# run `docker ps` again as ciuser, works.
root@c349e1d13b76:/# runuser -l ciuser -c 'docker ps'
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE            COMMAND       CREATED              STATUS              PORTS     NAMES
c349e1d13b76   nonroot:latest   "/bin/bash"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute             kind_satoshi
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was missing, I hadn't thought about Group ID's between container and host (WSL2 in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Part of the Docker metadata when it starts a container is which user it should run as; you wouldn't generally use `su` or `sudo`.

```sh
USER ciuser
CMD ["/bin/bash"] # or the actual thing the container should do
```

This is important because you can override the user when the container starts up, with the [`docker run -u`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#user) option; or you can [`docker run --group-add`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#additional-groups) extra groups.  These should typically be numeric group IDs, and they do not need to exist in the container's `/etc/passwd` or `/etc/group` files.

If the host's Docker socket is mode 0660 and owned by a `docker` group, you can [look up the corresponding group ID](https://askubuntu.com/questions/639990/what-is-the-group-id-of-this-group-name) and specify the container process has that group ID:

```sh
docker run \
  --group-add $(getent group docker | cut -d: -f3) \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  --rm \
  ci_container_staging \
  docker ps
```

(The container does not specifically need to be `--privileged`, though nothing stops it from launching additional privileged containers.)